# Print only second time nodes if repeating or only the first one xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this InputXML

```
<Tokens>
    <Element>ACNT=256265817; Expires=Wed, 15-Jul-2015 18:25:03 GMT; </Element>
    <Element>SESSIONID=F4ED9CD79D212993DE8479F97F74FD41; Expires=Wed, 15-Jul-2015 18:25:03 GMT; </Element>
    <Element>USER_ID=186900873; expires=Wed, 20-Jul-2008 06:25:03 GMT; </Element>
    <Element>CONFIRM=a4d6f57259de6a2d5d78d0f74bddc19b; expires=Wed, 20-Jul-2008 06:25:03 GMT; </Element>
    <Element>ID=186900873; expires=Wed, 20-Jul-2008 06:25:07 GMT; </Element>
    <Element>CONFIRM=a4d6f57259de6a2d5d78d0f74bddc19b; expires=Wed, 20-Jul-2008 06:25:07 GMT; </Element>
    <Element>SESSIONID=F4ED9CD79D212993DE8479F97F74FD41; Expires=Wed, 15-Jul-2015 18:25:03 GMT; </Element>
</Tokens>
```

And everytime the  one with latest expiration time will be always at the down. So blindly how to print the Items that are repeated second time. Note that expirytime changes when the element appears again. IF not repeating print the first element itself

Output is

```
<Tokens>
    <Element>ACNT=256265817; Expires=Wed, 15-Jul-2015 18:25:03 GMT; </Element>
    <Element>ID=186900873; expires=Wed, 20-Jul-2008 06:25:07 GMT; </Element>
    <Element>CONFIRM=a4d6f57259de6a2d5d78d0f74bddc19b; expires=Wed, 20-Jul-2008 06:25:07 GMT; </Element>
    <Element>SESSIONID=F4ED9CD79D212993DE8479F97F74FD41; Expires=Wed, 15-Jul-2015 18:25:03 GMT; </Element>
</Tokens>
```

How to give only the second  elements in generic manner without looking at the element values thru xslt 1.0. As Inside there might be values starting with different keys(ID/CONFIRM/SESSIONID/ACNT/GTID etc)

I tried set:distinct-values, but it is literally matching the whole text. which in this case there won't be any becuase of expiry time

set-distinct code inside stylesheet template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets">
<xsl:template match="/">
            <Tokens>
                <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(/Tokens/Element)">
                    <Element><xsl:copy-of select="."/></Element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Tokens>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you post the simplified XSL showing how did you use `set:distinct-values` exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Tokens/Element">
      <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::Element[substring-before(.,';')=substring-before(current(),';')])">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- `<xsl:template match="@* | node()">...` : Identity template. Copy nodes and attributes this template applied to to the output XML, unchanged.
- `<xsl:template match="Tokens/Element">...` : Overrides identity template for `Element` nodes that is direct child of `Tokens`. Duplicated `Element` node determined partially by the inner text before the first `;` character -using `substring-before()` function-. `Element` only copied to the output XML only *if it has no next sibling of the same `substring-before()` value*, in other words, for each distinct `substring-before()` value, only elements of the last occurrences are copied.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `set:distinct()` on a partial value. Use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) instead (with a small variation to get the last node of each group instead of first):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="elem-by-val" match="Element" use="substring-before(., ';')" />

<xsl:template match="/Tokens">
    <Tokens>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Element[count(. | key('elem-by-val', substring-before(., ';'))[last()]) = 1]"/>
    </Tokens>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that applied to your example input, the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Tokens>
   <Element>ACNT=256265817; Expires=Wed, 15-Jul-2015 18:25:03 GMT; </Element>
   <Element>USER_ID=186900873; expires=Wed, 20-Jul-2008 06:25:03 GMT; </Element>
   <Element>ID=186900873; expires=Wed, 20-Jul-2008 06:25:07 GMT; </Element>
   <Element>CONFIRM=a4d6f57259de6a2d5d78d0f74bddc19b; expires=Wed, 20-Jul-2008 06:25:07 GMT; </Element>
   <Element>SESSIONID=F4ED9CD79D212993DE8479F97F74FD41; Expires=Wed, 15-Jul-2015 18:25:03 GMT; </Element>
</Tokens>
```

is different from yours, because `USER_ID` is not the same as `ID`. If you want to ignore the label and look only at the value (which is dangerous, because ACNT and USER_ID might be identical by coincidence only), you could use

```
substring-before(substring-after(., '='), ';')
```

instead of:

```
substring-before(., ';')
```